# Insert an image to a layer with GIMP(2.10) by using script-fu

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

Hi all i am trying to open and insert an image to a new layer with console

```lisp
(define (xd imgPath)
  (let* ((theImage (car (gimp-file-load 1 imgPath "c.jpeg")))
         (theLayer (car (gimp-layer-new theImage 1500 1500 RGB-IMAGE "Layer 1" 100 LAYER-MODE-NORMAL))))
    (gimp-image-insert-layer theImage theLayer 0 0)
    (gimp-display-new theImage)))
```

But it shows black layer and image as background separately

[image: Screenshot]

How to combine them as one layer ?

Comment: See `(gimp-image-merge-down image merge-layer merge-type)` but this is only useful if your rew layer is smaller or not fully opaque.

Comment: This will answer your question https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2yhdaJhje8 . Also, when I wrote my first script fu functions I found excellent tutorials on the web.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAuJJ6P8Jxs&list=PLB18B51821B2370D4